# finding the position of a sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently making a battleships type game and I have created a user-friendly interface that highlights spaces on a grid in order to finish my hit system in this game I need to find the position of my sprite at a certain instance(for example when the player presses enter).

Comment: A [mcve] will enable people to try to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do to find the position of a sprite in pygame is you can use the `get_rect()` to find the `Rect` of the sprite, and then using the `.x` and `.y`. I'm assuming that you're sprites are `pygame.Surface`s.

```
find_loc(surface):
    loc = (surface.get_rect().x, surface.get_rect().y)
    return loc
# First, I get the Rect of your surface 
# With the Rect, I get the variables of the x and y
# I assign the .get_rect().x and .get_rect().y to a tuple which is assigned to variable 'loc'
# I return 'loc'
```

I hope this helps.